# Euler characteristics for planar vs. non-planar graphs

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

I've read from [this topology chapter](http://www.personal.psu.edu/axk29/TOPOLOGY/Chapter2.pdf), section 2.3.3, that there are two definitions of Euler Characteristics, one for general graphs defined as

$\chi(G) = V - E $

and another for "a graph G without loops embedded in the plane" as

$\chi(G) = V - E + F $

I am confused why there are two different definitions. In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic), it seems to be only the second definition.

For example, in the same page of the definition, a theorem says:

> Any connected graph is homotopy equivalent to the wedge of $k$
>   circles, with $k = \chi(G) − 1$

My guess is that it refers to be first definition. But I am not sure about this, and also about why $k = \chi(G) − 1$. The proof that follows only showed that the graph reduces to "several" circles.

Can someone help to clarify the definition here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are topological invariants. For the second definition you need a planar graph because only this way you have a canonical way to choose a face filling every loop...

And yes, the theorem refers to the first definition.