# How to find the Euler characteristic of a cellularly embedded graph, given only the vertices and edges?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Suppose that we are given a finite connected graph, i.e. the finite vertex set $V$ and a finite edge set $E\subseteq P(V)$.

> Is there an algorithm to find the Euler characteristic of any cellular embedding of our graph?

Recently I learned that it is not easy to find the "faces" if we are only given the vertex set and the edge set. We need to find an embedding into a compact connected surface in a such a way that the complement of the image of the graph is homeomorphic to a disjoint union of open discs (this type of embedding is called cellular, sometimes people also call it just a "map". The connected component of the complement of the image of graph gives us the faces). I am curious how one could find the Euler characteristic of our surface and therefore our surface (up to homeomorphism).

I suppose that after this edit it should be obvious to anybody, why this is NOT a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Euler characteristics for planar vs. non-planar graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2056602/euler-characteristics-for-planar-vs-non-planar-graphs)

Comment: @user10354138 No, it's not.

Comment: You know $V$ and $E$, so (e.g., as a simplicial complex) $\chi(G)=h_0(G)-h_1(G)=\lvert V\rvert-\lvert E\rvert$ is easily computed.

Comment: @user10354138 If you want to think of the graph as its own topological space, then sure, but it is clear from the question that we're thinking of embedding the graph into a 2D surface.

Comment: @user10354138 I would truly appreciate if you could revoke your close vote. It is not answering my question and is misleading for future people looking this up.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven The close vote will go away eventually on its own (I think they decay at a rate of one per day or so). I suggest not worrying about it.

Comment: What is the Euler characteristic of a graph?

Comment: @bof I edited my question. For me the Euler characteristic of a graph is the Euler characteristic of any surface that I can cellularly embed my graph into.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than speaking of the *Euler characteristic* of a graph, we traditionally speak of the *genus* of a graph, which is the least genus of a surface into which it can be embedded...

...but there is no way to find this number that improves substantially on finding all embeddings of the graph.

[This CS StackExchange answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/33230) outlines a method. The basic idea is that the global structure of the embedding is determined by some local decisions: for each vertex, you should determine the cyclic order of the edges out of that vertex.

Not all choices made at the different vertices are compatible, so we work out the ones that are, and now we can work out the faces of this embedding and determine the genus (or, if you prefer, the Euler characteristic). If we do this for all possible ways to choose the cyclic orders, we can get a bunch of embeddings, and then we can choose the best one.

There are better algorithms, and there are ways to speed up this algorithm so we don't have to check very possibility, but there's no fast algorithm. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_embedding#Computational_complexity) for some citations.

Comment: That is pretty surprising. Thank you for the nice answer and the comment to make clear why this no duplicate.